# Plotting Days of the year Python

Tags: python, datetime, plot

I am trying to plot time(axis-x) vs flow(axis-y). My data series "time" is Days of the year but it goes from 1 to 365. Any way to have the plot show on the x axis days/months (So Jan 1st would be 1-1, Feb 1st 1-2,...,Dec 1st 1-12) of the year instead of 1,2,3,4,5 all way to 365? Or do I need to add another column with the dates?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
enter code from matplotlib import pyplot
from math import log
time = list(mom6[0])
flow = list(mom6[1])
pyplot.scatter(x,y,linestyle = '--')
pyplot.ylabel('Flow (cfs)')
pyplot.xlabel('Time')
pyplot.title('Flow Duration')
pyplot.yscale('log')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()here
```

Also for pyplot.scatter(x,y,linestyle = '-') it will not connect the points. Also my array looks like:

```
  1,972
  10,847
  100,2234
  .
  .
  .
  365,1990
```

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use datetime to do the conversion:

(for insertion just after `time = list(mom6[0])`):

```
import datetime
start = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
dts = [ start + datetime.timedelta(days=int(ea)-1) for ea in time ]
time = [ ea.strftime('%d-%m') for ea in dts ]
```

Results in:

```
>>> time[:5]
>>> ['01-01', '02-01', '03-01', '04-01', '05-01']
```

Comment: I am receiving this  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' error. The dts = [ start + datetime.timedelta(days=ea-1) for ea in time ] is the problem. Not sure what I need to do?

Comment: Sorry, missed that your time array is strings (not int). Just do `dts = [ start + datetime.timedelta(days=int(ea)-1) for ea in time ]` instead.

Comment: It worked but when I used pyplot.scatter(time,flow,linestyle = '--'). Its calling it an ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 01-01. Will it be possible to use the actual date as the x axis?

Comment: Sure, skip the last line and just use `dts` as the data for x.